# Record syntax clarification

Tags: haskell

OK, so here's an unusual one. Every time you see an example of Haskell's record syntax, it always looks like

```
Sphere {center = 0, radius = 2}
```

or similar. My question is... are those curly brackets actually part of the record syntax? Or are they actually shorthand for layout? In other words, can you actually write something like

```
Sphere
  center = 0
  radius = 2
```

and have it work?

I doubt it would be very *useful* to do this - it takes up a lot of visual space - but I'm just curious as to whether this is syntactically *valid* or not.

Comment: IMHO, it's easy enough to just try it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Layout is an alternative to explicit braces and *semicolons*.

Record syntax uses explicit braces and *commas*.

So no, you can't use layout as part of record syntax.

[Haskell Report 2010 §2.7 Layout:](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-210002.7)

> Haskell permits the omission of the braces and semicolons used in several grammar productions, by using *layout* to convey the same information.

Comment: Even if the record syntax used semicolons, it would still not work as long as there is no rule that a constructor id triggers insertion of a brace ...

Answer (score 6):

OK, well I thought I'd put this question here in case anybody was interested. Having consulted the Haskell Report itself, it appears that the braces are *literally* a formal part of the record construct:

http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-690004.2.1

That means that these tokens actually have two distinct meanings in Haskell - as declaration delimiters when layout is not being used, and as record delimiters. I bet that leads to some interesting parser edge-cases!

(I also note in passing that `EmptyDataDecls` appears to be on by default in Haskell 2010, which is worth knowing...)

Comment: Regarding the parser: it's no issue because the other kind of braces can only appear after let, of, where and do. While the record braces are always protected by a constructor id.

Comment: @Ingo And `if`, and `=`, and... But yes, the crucial point is that records always start with a constructor name.

Comment: How can a { appear after `if` ?

Comment: @Ingo Well, you can indent after `if`, which presumably gets translated to a brace...

Comment: Huhh? This would be terrible, as `if {` is not valid syntax as long as an expression can't start with `{`.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid §2.7 says layout can only occur after `where`, `let`, `do` and `of`.

Answer (score 1):

After `Sphere`, the lexer won't insert a brace. Why should it? You dont expect a brace inserted in code like:

```
z = x
     + y
```

either, do you?

Comment: That's true. And yet, the above fragment does parse OK.

Comment: Yes, it does parse ok, *precisely because* there are no braces involved.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I thought the lexer simply inserts a `{` every time the indentation increases, and a `}` every time it decreases. Clearly what actually happens is even more complicated...

Comment: It does this only after the 4 magic tokens do, of, where and let. Otherwise it just does not insert a semicolon, when the indent is greater than the current one.

Comment: It seems that by asking this question, I've learned even more than just the answer to the actual question! :-D

Comment: Doesn't  matter, as long as your mental model does not deviate from reality too much :)

Comment: Part of the reason I asked in the first place is that I'm considering trying to build a Haskell parser some day... So this is all good stuff to know!

Comment: In this case you shouldn't hesitate to read the specification of the layout rule in the Haskell report. This can directly be transformed in a function that does the layout on a list of tokesn. That's how I did it in the Frege lexer, more or less.